# Java eclipse : Importing jar file in eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, rtc

I made plugin project named `DB2`.
Its purpose is to connect to database and update its values every time I save workitem
When I try to import `db2jcc.jar` file from my desktop it gives me error!

Following is screen shot of error i encountered while importing:

[image]

Comment: please attach the screenshot again

Comment: please update your error

Comment: please attach your screenshot or your error message, error code you have

Comment: It is not letting me add image. It says you should have at least reputation of 10

Comment: use http://imgur.com/ but I think that miss library in project

Answer (score 1):

Because miss the library jar in project.

Then press right click on name project inside **Window Package Explorer** and you can do one about two step:

1. So you have to go in **Properties** of you project  and go to **Java Build PAth**
2. Or **Build Path**->**configure Build Path** (right click on name project inside **window Package Explorer**).

So you have this window: [image]

Press **Add External JAR** , go to path of you file .jar, check the file **db2jcc.jar**, press **Finish** and now you will have the library in you project.

**OR**

Add the dependencie of **db2jcc** in the **pom.xml** if you build a Maven Project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.guoyukun.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[LINK](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cn.guoyukun.jdbc/db2jcc/1.4.2)

Comment: I made plugin project DB2. IT contains META-INF folder. I right click on that and try to import db2jcc.jar but it gives me error.  Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Report error using [stamp], copy in Paint, save image and upload in imgur.com

Comment: I uploaded image can you please check it?